# object reference not set to an instance of reference Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system, umbraco

I installed Umbraco cms  in a empty template of mvc4 application from NuGet package manager.

when i debugged the code it is throwing

> null reference exception object reference not set to an instance of reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've added Umbraco from nuget to an empty MVC project I'd guess that you've not run the Umbraco install.  The install sets up the database, lets you choose a startup scheme & so on.  If you've not configured a database I'd reckon you've downloaded but not installed Umbraco.

Try running your project in debug mode (if you're using Visual Studio press F5) & the install steps should be fired up or navigate to `http://localhost:4102/install/`

Answer (score 0):

Just re-create the solution and project without using dots (.)  or any other special character in names (both solution & project name)

Answer (score -1):

This is because some reference is null. Maybe you are calling something in the view that is null? Try to debug this code step by step and you will get the answer what is not initialized.